# Router stops working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I got a router that stops working, and I would need advice on how to troubbleshoot this.

Okay so here is the thing:

My parents got a router given by the internet provider. The router works fine until..

I come home from Uni. To stay over the summer. I stay in a other house on their yard. This house has its own router/wi-fi. This router is connected to theirs trought a internet cable. And as soon this router is turned on the problem starts.

The problem is that devices running iOS or Android get disconnected from their Wi-Fi network as sooon as they are not active (even if its just for a second). The computers who are conntected to their router trought a cable have a the same problem (Only one desktop).

My guess is that this happens because of IP-conflicts(?) on the network. My questions how can I troubbleshoot this to make sure what the problem is. And if it would be IP-conflicts (Wich it probably is) how could I fix this?

Comment: The second router should be set in "switch" mode. (Turn off DHCP)

Answer (score 0):

Most Likely **DHCP** is selected on the first router.

Depending on your router you need to log into it **"Second Router"**

And **Disable DHCP**.

Then you should not have any issues.